# Find duplicated sequences in a melted timeseries dataframe

Tags: r

I've got a wide/melted dataframe that looks like this:

```
year site   percent
2014 tex12  NA 
2015 tex12  12
2016 tex12  12.3
2017 tex12  14
2015 chi1   21
2016 chi1   34.5
2017 chi1   22
2015 ca1    12
2016 ca1    12.3
2017 ca1    14
```

I want to identify duplicated sequences - sites where `year` has the same value as `percent` for the length of that site - and add a new column with the name of the other duplicate. So in the example above, `tex12` and `ca1` are duplicated, hence:

```
year site   percent  duplicate
2014 tex12  NA       ca1
2015 tex12  12       ca1
2016 tex12  12.3     ca1
2017 tex12  14       ca1
2015 chi1   21       NA
2016 chi1   34.5     NA
2017 chi1   22       NA
2015 ca1    12       tex12
2016 ca1    12.3     tex12
2017 ca1    14       tex12
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Because it's the entire sequence that is duplicated - so for every `tex12` row it will print the other sequence it is duplicated with. Does this make sense, sorry?

Comment: And 2014 is NA anyway, so effectively `tex12` is starting in 2015, and has the same sequence as `ca1`

Comment: The duplicate is when two sites have the same years with the same values. So `tex12` and `ca1` have the same number of years and for these years the same values. I suppose I can first `drop_na` to get rid of NA rows to overcome that problem.

Comment: The same values with a floating point is difficult when you consider the precision

Comment: Would it make sense to convert that column to character then? And check duplicates as the same strings for the same years?

Comment: Do you need `df1  %>% group_by(year, percent) %>% mutate(duplicate = if(n() > 1) rev(site) else NA_character_) %>%group_by(site) %>% fill(duplicate, .direction = 'updown')`

Comment: Can you check the solution posted below.  Is it the logic you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R option :

```
#Create list of non-NA values by group
tmp <- tapply(df$percent, df$site, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
#Find which group match completely with the other one
mat <- outer(tmp, tmp, Vectorize(function(x, y) all(x %in% y)))
#Turn diagonals to FALSE so that it doesn't match with itself
diag(mat) <- FALSE
#get row/column number for matches
mat1 <- which(mat, arr.ind = TRUE)
#Create a reference dataframe with pairs that match.
pairs <- data.frame(site = rownames(mat1), duplicate = colnames(mat)[mat1[, 2]])
#merge to get the result
result <- merge(df, pairs, by = 'site', all.x = TRUE)
result
#    site year percent duplicate
#1    ca1 2015    12.0     tex12
#2    ca1 2016    12.3     tex12
#3    ca1 2017    14.0     tex12
#4   chi1 2015    21.0      <NA>
#5   chi1 2016    34.5      <NA>
#6   chi1 2017    22.0      <NA>
#7  tex12 2017    14.0       ca1
#8  tex12 2014      NA       ca1
#9  tex12 2015    12.0       ca1
#10 tex12 2016    12.3       ca1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L), site = c("tex12", "tex12", "tex12", 
"tex12", "chi1", "chi1", "chi1", "ca1", "ca1", "ca1"), percent = c(NA, 
12, 12.3, 14, 21, 34.5, 22, 12, 12.3, 14)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the precision is not taking into account for the 'percent' column, an option is to group by 'year', 'percent', create the `duplicate` as the `rev`erse of 'site' if there are more than 1 element, then we group by 'site' and `fill` the `NA` elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1  %>%
   group_by(year, percent) %>%
   mutate(duplicate = if(n() > 1) rev(site) else NA_character_) %>%
   group_by(site) %>%
   fill(duplicate, .direction = 'updown') %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#    year site  percent duplicate
#   <int> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>    
# 1  2014 tex12    NA   ca1      
# 2  2015 tex12    12   ca1      
# 3  2016 tex12    12.3 ca1      
# 4  2017 tex12    14   ca1      
# 5  2015 chi1     21   <NA>     
# 6  2016 chi1     34.5 <NA>     
# 7  2017 chi1     22   <NA>     
# 8  2015 ca1      12   tex12    
# 9  2016 ca1      12.3 tex12    
#10  2017 ca1      14   tex12
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L), site = c("tex12", "tex12", "tex12", 
"tex12", "chi1", "chi1", "chi1", "ca1", "ca1", "ca1"), percent = c(NA, 
12, 12.3, 14, 21, 34.5, 22, 12, 12.3, 14)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```